# Python: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'types.GenericAlias'

Tags: python

```
def inserter(nums, first, last, target):
    if first < last:
        mid = (first + last) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif target < nums[mid]:
            inserter(nums, first, mid - 1, target)
        else:
            inserter(nums, mid + 1, last, target)

    return 0


def searchInsert(nums, target):

    if target < nums[0]:
        return 0
    elif target > nums[len(nums) - 1]:
        return len(nums)

    inserter(list, 0, len(nums) - 1, target)


print(searchInsert((2, 4, 6, 8), 3))
```

Here line 6 throws the error in title. I've tried searching for it but can't find anything mentioning a comparison between int and types.GenericAlias. From what I understand, these types.GenreicAlias errors are relatively new, but I regress.

Comment: In your initial call to `inserter` you don't make a new list, you just pass in the type. Add `()` after the list to make a new list: `inserter(list(), 0, len(nums) - 1, target)`

Answer (score 1):

A useful exercise when you get strange errors is to just get a look at the values you're comparing - that will often show you something a bit more useful than an error about the types. So, we put these two lines just above the inner `if`:

```
print(target)
print(nums[mid])
```

and get:

```
3
list[1]
```

hold on, `list[1]`? You might not know what that  is, but its surely not what you expect `nums[mid]` to be.. so, hold on, what's `nums` then? Well, we print it and its:

```
list
```

Huh. It seems like you want a *particular* list (or similar) here, but you have the *type* `list`. So where did *that* come from?

Well, you haven't changed `nums` in this function, so it must come from where you call it. That looks like this:

```
inserter(list, 0, len(nums) - 1, target)
```

and, hey, there's that `list` again!
You probably wanted to pass `nums` instead:

```
inserter(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1, target)
```

and that clears the exception